# How can I cut a square shaped hole in cupboard glass?

Tags: glass, cutting

How can I cut a square hole in middle of glass without shattering it, without a drill? Can it be done with carbide scribe?

Comment: How large a hole, and how pretty does the cut need to be? How close to edges? Is the glass tempered? Please revise to add detail.

Comment: Might get a better answer if you say why you need the square hole in the glass.  Another solution to the square hole might happen.

Comment: My dad was a seriously old-school plumber/glazier. I've many times seen him take inner corners & square hole cuts out of a pane of glass. Scribe the 4 edges, cross-scribe between the corners *on the other side*; gently tappy-tap the back square, then just tap out the centre from the face side. He was a ninja. He'd had 40 years' practise, though. He could also cut circles out the same way for fan vents etc.

Answer (score 1):

Cutting a cornered hole (square, rectangular, triangle, etc.) will be difficult without a waterjet cutter machine. The stresses at the sharp corners will cause the glass to continue to break further than the desired shape. The corners need to remain rounded to distribute the stress in the glass.

Additionally, a glass-cutting scribe would not be able to set up a circumstance where the glass would crack only to the end of the scribe line but no further. With a drill one might be able to make the round corners needed, as well as some holes in the middle of the space to be removed, then scribe the edges of the shape between the corners. But a drill has been put  out of the scope of this question. Additionally, a scribe only scores the glass to make a weak point in the glass. It doesn't cut through the glass like in the movies. You need to stress (as in bend) the glass in the vicinity of the scribe, then the glass should break at the weak point. Trying to bend the glass inside the hole without bending the glass beyond the hole would be interesting to pull off. Odd-shaped pliers might be needed, depending on the size of the hole wanted.

The waterjet cutter machine will quite likely be able to make tighter-radius corners than a drill, achieving a closer-to-sharp-corner look. But without a rounded-corner-making device of some sort, the hole won't be cuttable or scribable without destroying the glass.

Comment: A drill and a deep-framed rod-saw would do it, cheaper. IF not tempered glass.